# What does the seek method in the FileInput class?

Tags: haxe

That (https://api.haxe.org/sys/io/FileInput.html) class has the seek(int, enum) method. What it does?

Answer (score 1):

It sets the position of the next character to be extracted from the input stream.

So it will change the input pointer position that will be use in the next `read` calls.